# XSLT: Image Link

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have been supplied with a XSLT feed by link which belongs to a agency we do work for.
The part I am stuck on is displaying the images and making them into links which go to the image in full view.

I have managed to display the image, but because I am cycling through the images, I am then unable to reuse that node as the link. Sorry if this does not make much sense. Here is the code:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="PHOTOS/IMAGEFILENAME">
 <xsl:element name="a">
 <xsl:attribute name="href">
 <xsl:value-of select="IMAGEFILENAME" />
 </xsl:attribute>

 <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
 <img>
 <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="IMAGEFILENAME" />
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:attribute name="width">63px</xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:attribute name="cursor">pointer</xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:attribute name="border">0</xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:attribute name="id"></xsl:attribute>
 </img>
 </xsl:element>

 </xsl:for-each>
```

And here is the data it is trying to access:

```
      -<PHOTOS> 
      <IMAGEFILENAME>http://test.co.uk/test1.jpg</IMAGEFILENAME
      <IMAGETHUMBFILENAME/>           
      <IMAGECAPTION>Reception area (Main)</IMAGECAPTION> 
      <PRINTQUALITYIMAGE>hhttp://test.co.uk/test2.jpg</PRINTQUALITYIMAGE> 
      <IMAGEFILENAME>http://test.co.uk/test3.jpg</IMAGEFILENAME> 
      <IMAGETHUMBFILENAME/>
```

So I need to establish how to use the `<IMAGEFILENAME>` as a link. Thanks

Comment: I don't completely follow your requirements. It would help a lot if you posted an example html segment that contained the required markup relating to the `IMAGEFILENAME` node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
<xsl:for-each select="PHOTOS/IMAGEFILENAME">
  <a href="{.}" target="_blank">
    <img src="{.}" width="63" border="0"/>
  </a>
</xsl:for-each>
```

do what you want?